# How to select items randomly from drop down by selenium Webdriver on Node.JS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I want to select items in randomly from an Angular row selection table.

```
<label ng-attr-for="industry_{{$index}}" ng-bind="industry[0]" class="ng-    binding" for="industry_9">Real Estate</label>
```

This is my test case:

```
 it ('Click on the start button ->> onboarding - screen 1', function() {

    element (by.id('START_BUTTON')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    expect(element(by.binding('industry[0]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
    //Capture Screenshoot
    browser.driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data){
    var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
    var fs = require("fs");
    fs.writeFile("onboarding-screen1.png", base64Data, 'base64',     function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
         });
    });
    //Select Industry and profession
    var random = new Random();
    int optionIndex = random.nextInt(industry_.getOptions().size() - 12);
    industry[0].selectByIndex(optionIndex++);
});
```

I'm also tried the code part below:

```
//Select Industry and profession
browser.driver.prototype.findElement = function(element) {
var doc = element.ownerDocument;
var store = doc['$business-registration$'] = doc['$business-registration$'] || {};
var id = "industry_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 0 + 1));
store[id] = element;
element[id] = id;
});
```

### Technical Info:

Selenium Webdriver (latest)

Jasmine JS 2

Protractor 2

Node.JS

Google Chrome (latest)

**The error from Node.JS is below:**

```
    Exception loading: c:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\exa
mple\demo.js
  Error - fail


Failures:

  1) Exception loading: c:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\example\demo.js Error
   Message:
     SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
   Stacktrace:
     SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.exports.executeSpecs (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\index.js:130:7)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\frameworks\
jasmine.js:82:14
    at Function.promise (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protract
or\node_modules\q\q.js:650:9)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\frameworks\
jasmine.js:63:14
```

Comment: So, are you getting an error? Is there a problem with your approach?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the post..

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected identifier means you have a syntax error in your code. I suspect it is line after the if(err) statement causing the problem. Try deleting one of the sets of closing brackets, to become:

```
fs.writeFile("onboarding-screen1.png", base64Data, 'base64',     function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
});

//Select Industry and profession
```

A good IDE should be able to pinpoint the line the error occurs on though

Comment: Thanks Steve, But the error isn't because of this line for sure.

Comment: OK then. Exactly which line does the error message point to in your project?

Comment: var random = new Random();
    int optionIndex = random.nextInt(industry_.getOptions().size() - 12);
    industry[0].selectByIndex(optionIndex++);

Comment: That also indicates the problem is with too many closing brackets. 'var' is the unexpected identifier because the function has been closed in the previous line. If you haven't actually tried my suggestion, do it

Comment: Let me guess, if replace the code block under '//Select Industry and profession' with a simple console.log statement, you still get the error?